# Plugin documention with RDoc in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins, rdoc

I'm writing a Rails 3 plugin and I'm using Engines. I have and app/ folder in my plugin with controller, models and views.

The problem is that when I want to generate documentation with RDoc it won't go into the app/ folder to parse the files in there. Is there an option I have to pass to it so it will know where to search for them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured it out on my own. I was using the rake task to generate documentation

```
rake doc:plugins
```

This runs the `rdoc` command but it passes the files to be parsed.
I eventually got around this by using rdoc directly in my plugin folder like so:

```
rdoc -o doc/plugins/my_plugin --title "My plugin Docs" --line-numbers --all --main README
```